# How to iterate through a range of given keys in a nested dictionary

Tags: python

I am iterating through a nested dictionary of stock prices that has the key: dates.

I am having trouble in being able to only get the prices of stocks at start date and end date.

This is a link to the nested dictionary.
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=TSLA&apikey=IMS80WN3J6S2ILKW

I've been trying a lot of different ways but not able to solve it for past 2 hrs:

```
starting_date  = '2020-02-13'
ending_date = '2020-02-11'

#data = the nested dictionary

opening_prices = []
series = data['Time Series (Daily)'] #Now were given the nested dictionary of the keys being dates and value being a dictionary of info: price.
for date in series:
    if date == starting_date:
        for data, price in date.items()
            opening_prices.append(float(price['1. open']))
#we are retrieving the opening prices of the nested dict.
#For this attempt, I get the error of date being str type.
#I still don't know how to stop at the end_date as I tried a while loop, but it failed.
```

Comment: `date == starting_date or date == ending_date` don't work?

Comment: The program doesn't even recognize the starting date. So with date == start_date: it totally ignores the starting date and appends the first opening price to the list no matter what.

Comment: Iterating on a dictionary goes through its keys only, i.e. `for date in series:` means `date` is a string. Use `for date, day_vals in series.items():`

Comment: Okay I'll try that right now thanks.

Comment: I just tried it and it still ignores the start_date.

Comment: Please check the updated answer that also considers all dates between the two given dates. Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to get just the values for 2 dates you could do:

```
>>> res = [float(series[k]['1. open']) for k in (starting_date, ending_date)]
>>> res
[741.84, 768.79]
```

For a range of dates, it can be changed to

```
>>> starting_date  = '2020-02-11'
>>> ending_date = '2020-02-13'
>>> res = [float(series[k]['1. open']) for k in series if starting_date <= k <= ending_date]
>>> res
[741.84, 777.87, 768.79]
```

Comment: My goal is to append all the values of the opening prices between the starting_date and ending_date. I'm playing around with the DateTime module right now.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that you were trying to access keys from strings.

```
data = {
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "TSLA",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-02-14",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2020-02-14": {
            "1. open": "787.2200",
            "2. high": "812.9700",
            "3. low": "785.5000",
            "4. close": "800.0300",
            "5. volume": "15631446"
        },
        "2020-02-13": {
            "1. open": "741.8400",
            "2. high": "818.0000",
            "3. low": "735.0000",
            "4. close": "804.0000",
            "5. volume": "26289348"
        },
        "2020-02-12": {
            "1. open": "777.8700",
            "2. high": "789.7500",
            "3. low": "763.3700",
            "4. close": "767.2900",
            "5. volume": "12022470"
        }
    }
}

starting_date  = '2020-02-12'
ending_date = '2020-02-14'

opening_prices = []
closing_prices = []
for date in data['Time Series (Daily)']:
    if (date == starting_date):
        opening_prices.append(float(data['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['1. open']))
    if (date == ending_date):
        closing_prices.append(float(data['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['4. close']))

print(opening_prices)
print(closing_prices)
```

Which yields:

```
[777.87]
[800.03]
```

### All dates between

```
between_dates = []
from datetime import date
s_date_split = starting_date.split('-')
e_date_split = ending_date.split('-')
dstart = date(int(s_date_split[0]), int(s_date_split[1]), int(s_date_split[2]))
dend = date(int(e_date_split[0]), int(e_date_split[1]), int(e_date_split[2]))

for _date in data['Time Series (Daily)']:
    curr_date_split = _date.split('-')
    d_curr = date(int(curr_date_split[0]), int(curr_date_split[1]), int(curr_date_split[2]))
    if dstart < d_curr < dend:
        between_dates.append(float(data['Time Series (Daily)'][_date]['4. close']))


print(between_dates)
```

Which yields:

```
[804.0]
```

Comment: Oh I forgot to add the correct appending argument part:  ['Time Series (Daily)'][date]['1. open']. I understand now. Thanks!

Comment: You said "I am having trouble in being able to only get the prices of stocks at start date and end date." this means to me that you want only the start date and end date. Do you also want all the in between dates?

Comment: You can convert the date in a more elegant way, of course. I left it to you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
starting_date  = '2020-02-01'
ending_date = '2020-02-13'

#data = the nested dictionary

opening_prices = []
series = data['Time Series (Daily)']
for date in series:
    if date >= starting_date and date <= ending_date:
        opening_price = series[date]['1. open']
        opening_prices.append(float(opening_price))


print(opening_prices)
```

#### Output

```
[741.84, 777.87, 768.79, 800.0, 730.55, 699.92, 823.26, 882.96, 673.69]
```

Comment: Oh my gosh. You guys are life savers. I experimented so many different ways and had trouble with it for so long. I understand what I did wrong. Thanks so much. I can move to my next part of my project. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Hi, so I'm applying the same concept to retrieve data of each stock attribute. This concept worked until it reached the volume attribute. For some reason, I receive the error 'KeyError: 'Time Series (Daily)'. I was wondering why I get this error when I never got this error for the past attributes: open, high, low, close.

Comment: The error occurs when I assign: series = data['Time Series (Daily)']. Everything is typed correctly.

Comment: I can't see any reason why volume would be different to ohlc.  I'd need to see your code to find out why you're getting that error.

Comment: Is it okay if I send you my code? We can use codeshare if willing: https://codeshare.io/2BkoJL

Comment: Sure, go ahead.